# How to get only time difference

Tags: angular, typescript

How to get time difference only:

My Code:

```
const date = moment.utc().format();
const localtime = moment.utc(date).local.format();  // 2022-07-01t18:53:00 +05:30
```

how can I get only difference +05:30 from localtime
I only need time difference I don't want entire date(2022-07-01t18:53:00)

Kindly help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const localtime = moment.utc(date).local.utcOffset(); // This will be minutes
const localHours = Math.floor(localtime/60);
const localMinutes = localtime - localHours*60;
const localOffset = (localHours>0?"+":"") + localHours+":"+localMinutes;
```

Get the offset from the moment date, it will be in minutes, so you convert to hours and minutes. Then you add the + sign if it is positive.

Comment: Using momentjs is not exactly recommended I’m afraid?

Comment: Recommended or not is out of the scope of the question, which is "How do I get the offset from a moment date object?" ...